# Getting an error while trying to download an update in uwp

Tags: uwp

I'm getting a The operation attempted to access data outside the valid range (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000000B) error on this line. What causes this?

```
IReadOnlyList<StorePackageUpdate> storePackageUpdates = await context.GetAppAndOptionalStorePackageUpdatesAsync();
```

Comment: Hello, is your app already on the Microsoft Store? This method will request update information of the app in the store, which requires you to upload at least one package of the app in the store.

Comment: Hello Saurav Kumar, did you find a solution? Thanks.